# How to start fragment using action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

Here is my HomeFragment and i just wanna ask if i click the shopping cart actionbar CartFragment will start appearing.

```
        case R.id.action_shoppingcart:

        Toast.makeText(this, "shopping cart selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        return true;
```

[here's my screenshot of menu with actionbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYul6.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear but I will attempt an answer. Assuming you have defined your current fragment in a frame in the activity XML you just need to switch the fragment in that frame.

```
Fragment fragment = new CartFragment();
// Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment)
               .commit();
```

Comment: @paulbuscano haha! you're most welcome. Welcome to stackoverflow. Next time please don't use CAPS however worked up you are, doesn't go well with the SO community! ;)